# MySQL InnoDB Indexing a column longer than max length

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have table in mysql where I store some urls. The column width is 2048 character. Most urls stored will be longer than 1000 characters. I do lookups by url often so I wanted to index it but the max length allowed on the index is 255 characters.

I still added the index and it seems like the column is being partially indexed. How does this work? And is it performant?

Here is an Explain query I ran on a lookup by url

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT `code` 
FROM tinyurl 
WHERE url ='//mysite.com/iframe.php?target=product&lookupid=5e6183640e7f943fc21bbc2be373b4b0&code=41432';
```

Results:
[image]

*NOTE: The actual url value was longer I removed some items for privacy puposes*

I can see that 768 bytes are being used from the url key but how would this actually work? Is this indexing only the first 255 characters for the url column?

Comment: Yes, it's only indexing the first 255 characters. What other answer do you expect? And, you know, this is all described in the manual.

Comment: @fancyPants forgive me, I must have missed it in the manual. I would expect it to not create an index at all. But I would assume the index it did create is not useless because I could have many entries where the first 255 characters are exactly the same.

Comment: Its not "useless".  Yes, the index might include some rows that don't match after 255, but the `WHERE url=...` will simply check each one and deliver the desired result.